# Todo list app using notifications/reminder

Tags: ios, swift

I have been teaching myself how to make iOS apps using Swift through a udemy course. I learned how to build a basic To Do list app but I wanted to build more to it by adding weekly reminders/notification setting.

I want the app to count how many times one has completed an item on the list and to send a notification every weekend telling the user the number of times that the item has been completed. For example, if "go to the gym" is on the list, the user is able to check it off every time he "goes to the gym". Then, throughout the week, the app will keep count of how many times "go to the gym" has been checked off and will alert the user at the end of the week "you completed 'go to the gym' x amount of times"

I've been trying to google how to build this function in the app but I am thoroughly confused as to how to approach this issue. Is this even possible? I want the app to send reminders even if the app is closed.

Comment: Those things you want to do are all possible. For counting the number of times user has completed a task you need to use some persistence method like Core Data or Realm(since you're new on iOS I'd recommend prototyping with UserDefaults). To send the notifications you can use local notifications or push notifications. Since you wanna send those every weekend even if the app is closed you should use push notifications(I think is possible to use local notification since they allow scheduling but the code probably will be very boring, the push notification is easier and more reliable).

Comment: thank you! I have been storing values such as list items to userdefaults. I was especially confused about the difference between local and push notifications but i think this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You should do some research about integrating some server side logic with your app.

When it comes to recall a user with some features like notification I think you should start to manage Users in your app.

So that user can signup, you can recognise the user that subscribe to your notification logic and recall him with a routine you will enable on your server.

I think you should do some research on this topics:

- Creating a basic server with a simple architecture like Firebase
- Handle User Signup
- Ask for Notification
- Create a routine (basically a function that is ran every day/week) on your server that checks for user activities and send notification based on your rules

There is a chance you can build that without using a server side logic, but I really advise you to learn how to create a dynamic app that integrates with API ( Server Side Logic ) that you build for your future projects.

Hope it helps,

Have a nice day

Comment: Why would you need a server for this? Why would you need user signup? All of this can be done locally with far much less work.

Comment: It depends on the goals of the project. As a beginner question I gave my suggestion for best investment in learning. In my opinion is a better approach to understand the opportunity to create a Retention project with users. Guest users provide a lean development solution but lacks in other long terms opportunities.

Comment: I thought about this option as well. I just learned to store users sign ups using aws.amazon.com so would that work as well instead of Firebase?

Comment: @coopermoc you should really checkout solutions like Firebase. If you plan to build a project for your startup. Also Parse-Server is a great solution. The reason is that those services are designed for simple project development and its easy to add features like notifications, analytics, data storage.